# Induced norm of identity matrix plus rank one matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

Let $\alpha\in(0,1)$ and $\hat{g}$ be a unit vector. I would like to bound/find an inequality for the norm of $I - \alpha\hat{g}\hat{g}^\top$. In particular, for the induced norm.
$$
\parallel I - \alpha \hat{g}\hat{g}^\top\parallel_I = \sup_{u\neq 0} \frac{||(I - \alpha \hat{g}\hat{g}^\top) u||}{||u||}
$$
All I could think of was
$$
\parallel I - \alpha \hat{g}\hat{g}^\top\parallel_I \leq ||I||_I + \alpha||\hat{g}\hat{g}^\top||_I = 1 + \alpha ||\hat{g}\hat{g}^\top||
$$
But this seems quite loose since we are not using the fact that we are subtracting the outer product?

Answer (score 2):

If the underlying vector norm is the Euclidean norm then one can estimate
$$
\|(I-\alpha gg^T)x\|_2 \le \|x\|_2 + \alpha \|g\|_2 \cdot |g^Tx| \le (1+\alpha)\|x\|_2.
$$
To get a better estimate, one can decompose $x = sg + u$ with $u\perp g$.
This implies $\|x\|_2^2 = \|u\|_2^2 + s^2$.
Then
$$
\|(I-\alpha gg^T)x\|_2^2 = \|x - \alpha sg\|_2^2 = \|sg+u-\alpha sg\|_2^2
= \|u\|_2^2 + (1-\alpha) s^2 \le \|x\|_2^2.
$$
Hence $\|I-\alpha gg^T\|\le 1$. In addition $\|I-\alpha gg^T\|=1$ if $n>1$. To see this take $x\perp g$. If $n=1$, i.e., the vector space is one-dimensional, then $I-\alpha gg^T = (1-\alpha)I$.

Comment: I don't understand the last two arguments. How can you show that the norm of the matrix is exactly equal to $1$ for $n>1$?

Comment: If $x$ is orthogonal to $g$ then $(I-\alpha gg^T)x=x$.

Comment: This is not true, this holds only in 2 dimensions..

Comment: I don't think you can decompose $x = sg + u$ unless we are in 2 dimensions. Otherwise $\{g, u\}$ would be a basis. And the size of the basis is the dimension of the space

Comment: The vector $u$ depends on $x$. The decomposition is: we split $x$ in a vector that is parallel to $g$, which is $sg$, and a vector orthogonal to $g$, which is $u$.